# Как создать проект в Visual Studio Community 2015 под android на c++?

Tags: android, c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, visual-studio-2015

Хочу создать проект в *VS2015* под *Android*, чтобы разработка была на *C++*. Пробую:

<kbd>Новый проект</kbd> → <kbd>Шаблоны</kbd> → <kbd>Другие языки</kbd> → <kbd>Visual C++</kbd> → <kbd>Кроссплатформенные</kbd> → <kbd>Android</kbd> → <kbd>Простое приложение (Android, Gradle)</kbd>

При этом открывается код на *java*.

Comment: и маленькое дополнение: насколько реально делать приложения под android в VS и под c++?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вы можете использовать VS для разработки приложений на C++ под андроид. Как создать проект и какой написано тут: 
 [ссылка](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/dn707591.aspx)!

P.S. Другой вопрос - зачем? Если вас засмущало уже на этом этапе разработка, тогда может стоит посмотреть в другую сторону, более простые варианты есть. использовать C++ в разработке каких-то простых приложений под андроид - это стрелять из пушки по воробьям. есть упрощенный вариант, если уж C++ так важен для вас - Qt QML. вы декларируете весь интерфейс на QML(основы можно изучить за пару часов) и описываете логику на C++. очень просто и никакого кода на java.